# Ansible installation of MySQL 8 - installing repository without mysql-apt-config

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, mysql-8.0

I am trying to install MySQL 8 automatically with ansible.

However, this installation requires obtaining of [mysql-apt-config](https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.3-1_all.deb). Which, when installed, opens a config window

[image: mysql-apt-config-install]

I would like to bypass this config and rather obtain the repository in the ansible using `apt_repository`.

What is the correct address? Where can I find this repository address so I could download and install MySQL using `apt`?

<s>This makes a problem for ansible - I don't know how to put an option in this window. I tried [expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html)</s>

```
- name: install mysql repo
  expect:
    command: "dpkg -i /tmp/mysql-apt-config.deb"
    responses: 
      Question:
        - response4
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
```

however that raises following error

```
TASK [mysql : install mysql repo] ******************************************************************************
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The pexpect python module is required"}
```

I checked, and pexpect module is available.

Is there any possibility to add MySQL repositories manually, without this prompt?

Comment: are you sure the python module is installed on the correct server (executor or target)?

Comment: i am. I checked both of them.

Comment: apart from that, I also added ansible equivalent of `pip install pexpect` just above.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Search for "mysql-apt-config silent install".

Comment: Thanks. This is the keyword I was looking for

Comment: Yeah this is true, that I specified the question too much. Therefore I changed the question and title to return it to the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case somebody would be looking for similar answer:

To install MySQL 8 using ansible, this is the repository you should add:

```
- name: Add MySQL 8 ubuntu xenial repository
  apt_repository: 
    repo: "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial mysql-8.0"
    state: present
```

Edit the address to match your distribution. The rest of the process is automatic and whats more - silent.

I found the repository address [here.](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,666369,666533#msg-666533)

Comment: You can find the latest distro in apt at `https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/` (in parenthasis below the download of the keyring installer).

Answer (score 5):

Another way to select your version:

```
- name: Try to specify preference for mysql
  shell: echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-server select mysql-8.0 | debconf-set-selections
  become: yes

# Download mysql debian package
- name: Add mysql apt-config debian
  apt: deb=http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb update-cache=yes
  become: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

After copy/download the repo, do that.
The option register answer the asks.

```
    - name: 'Add repo mysql'
      apt:
        deb: /etc/repo.d/mysql-apt-config_0.8.25-1_all.deb
      register: mysql_upstream_repository_installation
      become: yes
    - name: 'update'
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        update_cache: yes
      become: yes
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).